# Python call grep to fail

Tags: python

I want to execute this command in Python

```
grep keyMessage logFile.log > keyMessageFile.log
```

This is what I done now

```
from subprocess import call

keyMessage= 'keyMessage'
call(["grep", keyMessage,  "logFile.log"])
```

but I don't know how to add the `> keyMessageFile.log` part

By the way, the reason why I use grep is because it's much faster than use read file then compare string then write file

**#Update**
There is the slower python code I write

```
keyMessage= 'keyMessage'

with open('logFile.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        with open(keyMessage+ '.txt', 'a') as newFile:
            if(keyMessage not in line):
                continue
            else:
                newFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Why call `grep` from `python`?

Comment: @MichaelMao Your updated code opens and closes the output file for each line, which will still be slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this (reasonably safely too) is:

```
from subprocess import check_call
from shlex import quote
check_call('grep %s logFile.log > keyMessageFile.log' % quote(keyMessage), shell=True)
```

However unless you really need the regex matching capabilities of `grep`, and you end up reading `keyMessageFile.log` in your program anyway, I don't think the following would be unreasonably slow:

```
def read_matching_lines(filename, key):
    with open(filename) as fp:
      for line in fp:
        if key in line:
          yield line

for matching_line in read_matching_lines('logFile.log', keyMessage):
    print(matching_line)
```

Comment: "*unless you really need the regex matching capabilities of grep*" - what's wrong with the regex capabilities of python?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the 2nd sample you give. the function is named read_matching_lines or read_matching_files and what is matching_line

Comment: I got it and the 2nd sample is vert faster than my python code. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) has a parameter `stdout`. Pass an file opened for writing to it.

```
with open("keyMessageFile.log", "w") as o:
    keyMessage= 'keyMessage'
    call(["grep", keyMessage,  "logFile.log"], stdout=o)
```

`subprocess.call` is the old API, you should use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
    import sys
    os.system('grep %s logFile.log > keyMessageFile.log' % 'looking string')
```